# Need to select a checkbox, based on text in another div

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

```
<div class="bli-category">
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="placementtrack by $index">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-1 bli-category-checkbox">
<input class="bli-check-box ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-click="addPlacement" ng-checked="checkedPlacementIndex" ng-model="selectedPlacement">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8 bli-category-content">
<div class="ng-binding" ng-bind="placement.placementName">page_details</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to select the checkbox in `class='bli-check-box ng-valid'` for the text in `class='ng-binding'`
When I try to get the xpath like

```
//input[@class='bli-check-box ng-valid']
```

it selects all the 4-5 checkboxes

Comment: if there is more than 1 control with given class name then it would select all of them

Answer (score 0):

To select the `checkbox` in `class='bli-check-box ng-valid'` with respect to the text in `class='ng-binding'` i.e. **page_details** you can use the following `xpath` :

```
//div[@class='bli-category']//div[@class='ng-binding' and contains(.,'page_details')]//preceding::input[@class='bli-check-box ng-valid']
```

> **Note** : As the element is an `Angular` element you have to induce `wait` for the **`element to be clickable`** before attempting to click.

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[text='page_detials' and class='ng-binding']/../preceding-sibling::div//input[class='bli-check-box ng-valid']
```

The above xpath starts with finding the node which has the custom text that you know. It then traverses to its parent and then its previous sibling which in your case houses your required `input` node. So after traversing to the `div` you select its child which is your required `input` node.